# Responsive Menu Icon not shown - T3 Joomla Framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, joomla3.0

For some reasons, the Bootstrap menu icon does not appear when resizing the browser or accessing by mobile devices.

Does anyone has some ideas?
I am using the T3 Framework for Joomla.
Here is the link to the website:

http://morgerock.schurtertom.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the mistake... I had to enable the function in the template manager...
my mistake